# Image appearing to the left of its containing div

Tags: html, css, image

I have a series of divs that each contain one image.  The images are (ideally) going to be centered vertically and horizontally within the divs, but right now the left side of each image is showing up about 6 pixels to the left of the left-most boundary of the containing div.  How can I get them to display properly?

```css
.SmallImageContainer {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 70px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.SmallImageBox {
 float: left;
 height: 70px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: pink;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.SmallImageBox img {
 display: block;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin: auto;
 border: solid thin #787878;
 max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="SmallImageContainer">
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm001" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm002" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm003" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm004" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm005" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    </div> <!-- class="SmallImageContainer" -->
```

Comment: I've updated your question with functional images. I don't see the issue, however. Please make additional updates to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: doesnt seems like any thing wrong?

Comment: Okay.  I guess that means something in the proceeding CSS is messing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max-width: 100%;` instead of `90%` (which was giving you the 6px margin), and resolve the border overflow issue with `box-sizing: border-box;` (it won't be necessary if the img don't have border).

And, to vertically align the image, you can first add a `position: relative;` to it, and then just put it at `top: 50%;` and with `margin-top: -50%;`, and you've got it, see:

```css
.SmallImageContainer {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 70px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.SmallImageBox {
 float: left;
 height: 70px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: pink;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.SmallImageBox img {
 display: block;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin: auto;
 border: solid thin #787878;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="SmallImageContainer">
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm001" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm002" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm003" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm004" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    <div class="SmallImageBox"><img id="sm005" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
    </div> <!-- class="SmallImageContainer" -->
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't _resolve_  the border overflow. Notice that computed width of the image is `48px`. The border doesn't overflow the parent `div` because you've set `max-width: 100%`, instead of `width: 100%`.

Comment: @matewka Even using `width: 100%`, the `box-sizing: border-box` will still be necessary. BTW, I'm using Chrome. Try it yourself on the inspector.